# How to test props passed from parent component in Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, ts-jest

when testing props passed down from the parent component, the props (useState) does not update. I have tried update API form Enzyme but not to avail. I need to handle state in the parent component (home.tsx) for when I make api call. I am honestly pretty new to testing and wonder if using Cypress would be more beneficial in this specific case. Appreciate your help in advance.

```
// home.tsx

function Home() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    emailAddress: "",
  });
 
  const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // handle submit
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <UserInputForm
            userInfo={userInfo}
            setUserInfo={setUserInfo}
          />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}


export default Home;
```

```
// user-input-form.tsx

import React, { useState } from "react";
import ErrorMessageDisplay from "../commons/error-message/error-message";
import { ButtonContainer } from "../commons/nav-button/style";

interface UserInputFormProps {
  userInfo: UserInputFormType;
  setUserInfo: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<UserInputFormType>>;
}

export interface UserInputFormType {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  emailAddress: string;
}


function UserInputForm({
  userInfo,
  setUserInfo,
}: UserInputFormProps) {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    emailAddress: "",
  });

  const handleSetErrorMessage = (key: string, message: string) => {
    setErrorMessage((prevUserInfo) => ({
      ...prevUserInfo,
      [key]: message,
    }));
  };

  const handleUserInfo = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>
  ) => {
    setUserInfo((prevUserInfo) => ({
      ...prevUserInfo,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Title>Please Enter User Information</Title>
      <label>
        <FieldContainer>
          <LabelTextBox>
            <LabelText>First Name</LabelText>
            <ErrorMessageDisplay text={errorMessage.firstName} />
          </LabelTextBox>
          <InputBox data-testid="user-information-input">
            <input
              name="firstName"
              type="text"
              placeholder="First Name"
              aria-label="firstName-input"
              onChange={handleUserInfo}
              value={userInfo.firstName}
              aria-label="firstName-input"
            />
          </InputBox>
        </FieldContainer>
      </label>
      <label>
        <FieldContainer>
          <LabelTextBox>
            <LabelText>Last Name</LabelText>
            <ErrorMessageDisplay text={errorMessage.lastName} />
          </LabelTextBox>
          <InputBox>
            <input
              name="lastName"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Last Name"
              onChange={handleUserInfo}
              value={userInfo.lastName}
              aria-label="lastName-input"
            />
          </InputBox>
        </FieldContainer>
      </label>
      <label>
        <FieldContainer>
          <LabelTextBox>
            <LabelText>Email</LabelText>
            <ErrorMessageDisplay text={errorMessage.emailAddress} />
          </LabelTextBox>
          <InputBox>
            <input
              name="emailAddress"
              type="email"
              value={userInfo.emailAddress}
              onChange={handleUserInfo}
              aria-label="emailAddress-input"
            />
          </InputBox>
        </FieldContainer>
      </label>
      <ButtonContainer>
         <button>submit</button>
      </ButtonContainer>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default UserInputForm;
```

```
// user-input-form.test.tsx
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";


const setup = () => {
  const onClickCallback = jest.fn();
  const myInitialState = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    fnameKana: "",
    lnameKana: "",
    gender: "",
    age: "",
    vehicleType: "",
    postCode: "",
    city: "",
    address: "",
    emailAddress: "",
  };
  const utils = render(
    <UserInputForm
      userInfo={myInitialState}
      setUserInfo={onClickCallback}
    />
  );
  const input = utils.getByLabelText('firstName-input')
  return {
    input,
    ...utils,
  };
};


test("it checks input validation", () => {
  const { input, ...utils } = setup();
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "not so test" } });
  expect((input as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe("not so test");
});
```

test props from parent component. state did not update after simulating change in test.

Comment: Think about the responsibility of the thing you're testing, the `UserInputForm`. It's not to update the state; the parent owns that (and arguably shouldn't just be passing `setUserInfo` around). It's just to _call the callback_ (or presumably update its own state, but `checkRequiredField` is never called).

Comment: @jonrsharpe the state (userInfo) gets updated every time the value of the input changes which I am trying to test. Out of curiosity, why I should't be passing setUserInfo around? Should I pass down a function that handles state change instead? If I create a new state in the child component, I can successfully access the value via Jest API however, I have no access to props passed down from the parent component.